# I don't know why I got the error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm running the program using a notebook on vscode and using anaconda base but I'm getting an error:
"invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''" ở dòng k = int(input("k = ")). I don't see my mistake anywhere because when I use colab it still works normally I need help :(((
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fw1Dm.png)

I tried entering k = 3 directly and it worked normally but when I wanted to enter from the keyboard I got an error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hb2mM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Jupyter extension in your vs code and select the correct kernel in the top right corner of your Jupyter notebook in vs code
[image: select the correct kernel here]

Note that the input is in the top of vs code:
[image: input in the top]

If you don't pass a number to the input it will fail.